# Referencing environment variables in weblogic.xml

Tags: java, logging, weblogic

I'm trying to configure logging so that the logfile will be put into the server's log directory, without hard-coded directories. Apparently thats rocket science in Weblogic, as ${weblogic.Name} is not interpolated:

```
<weblogic-web-app>
<logging>
    <log-filename>servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/ohcomeon.log</log-filename>
    <logging-enabled>true</logging-enabled>
    <rotation-type>byTIme</rotation-type>
    <file-count>30</file-count>
    <file-time-span>24</file-time-span>
</logging>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Is there a way?